# show notification by javascript

Tags: javascript, php

I'm using [this](http://themeforest.net/item/proteus-responsive-admin-web-app/11725885) template and there's a sample page which covers notifications. There are numerous buttons which show a notification when pressed. I took a look at the button's source:

```
<a id="toastr_show" href="#" class="btn btn-dark">Show</a>
```

I found the javascript source code.

```
function runToastr(obj){
    $(obj.elem).on( "click", function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        toastr.options.closeButton = false;
        toastr.remove();
        switch(obj.type){
...
```

I wonder how I can 'call' this notification from php?

Comment: Why want you to trigger client actions from php?

Comment: I'm processing provided user credentials and want to let the user know if his password was wrong

Comment: Long story short, you can't. You can use ajax to dynamically load content or even send data to a php script, but you can't have PHP send data to a client (generally. You could try and use sockets, but PHP isn't meant for that).

Comment: Your final rendered page can have something like `<script>showYourNotification({"msg": "..."})</script>`

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, @vp_arth

Comment: Call JavaScript from PHP? I think you mean call PHP from JavaScript, right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a few ways for you. 
HTML5 solutions:

1. Websocket
2. Server-sent Events

`Websocket` create a two-way tunnel and `Server-sent Events` create a one-way tunnel from server to client. Both of them can make your server side program send a "notification" to your client, so that you can display it via Javascript.
How ever, HTML5 doesn't work in any browser. And its programing is kind of difficult.

The easiest way is to make a `AJAX` request periodicity. However, it means the notification is not real time. And a short period will cost batteries on your client and resources on your server

Answer (score 1):

To trigger notifications from a server side to a client, the following technologies may be implemented:
1. Websockets. This is a relatively new feature in HTML5. It keeps a CPU-less-intensive port to the server open and listens to that port. Now the server passes whatever it must pass to the client and the client renders it real time. Its application is in chat applications. But so far, PHP capability for that is kinda limited. NodeJS however has [Socket.IO](http://socket.io) with a lot more. You might want to read about [Websockets here](https://www.google.com.gh/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=5&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0ahUKEwj18be2scnNAhWCHsAKHRYMB_AQFgg5MAQ&url=https%3A%2F%2Fen.wikipedia.org%2Fwiki%2FWebSocket&usg=AFQjCNHtcQ0o3Xzm7NoiB9Pyp76Hlcn_-Q&sig2=gpICVeZMY2ZMTk1lgj5skg).

2. A clever workaround is to request for notifications using an interval request. You do this by simply wrapping the request inside a JavaScript `setInterval()` method. If you are using jQuery, be sure to put this into the `$(document).ready(function() {});`